# Create default instance of SQL Server 2008 while already having named instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, named-instance

I want to setup default instance of SQL Server while I already have setup named `SQLServer` instance while installing SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server Management Studio. How do I do that?

Comment: Just install SQL Server 2008 (or a newer version - 2008 will be out of support pretty soon!) and choose the "default" (unnamed) instance when installing....